# Multiply different fields based on field value in CTE construct

Tags: sql, firebird

In a CTE construct I want to know if there is a way to multiply different fields between fields in CTE definition and fields in main query based on a field value in the main query ?

For example in CTE construct there are `Width1` and `Width2` fields. In the main query there are `Height1`, `Height2` and `DIM_Type`

Is it possible to get two calculated fields `Result1` and `Result2` from `Width1 * Height1` if `DIM_Type = 1` and from `Width2 * Height2` if `DIM_Type = 2` respectively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle, which more or less does the same as above: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d24e7/10
You will need to change 111 and 222 with the columns which holds height1 and heigh2 respectively

```
with propCte as (

  select 
    width1,
    width2,
    dim_type
  from 
    props

)

select
  case dim_type
    when 2 then propCte.width1 * 111
    else propCte.width2 * 222
  end as computed
from 
  propCte
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select case 
    when DIM_Type = 1 then Width1 * Height1
    else  Width2 * Height2
end CalculatedField
from cte
```